# Referring to Winforms objects in SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, winforms, t-sql

For context, I'm working with a genealogical database which is stored in SQL Server. To view the info, I am creating a Winforms app in Visual Studio which will allow each person to be viewed as a record in a form called `PersonForm`.

`PersonTable` is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE PersonTable 
(
    PersonID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
    FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    LastName VARCHAR(50),
    Gender BINARY,
    MotherID INT,
    FatherID INT,
);
```

My end goal is to have a dataGridView object (called 'childOfCurrent') on a form that will show all of the people listed as children of the currently viewed record (using self join in the `PersonTable`).

I have succeeded in listing all of the mothers and their children using a self join SQL query:

```
SELECT
    C.PersonID AS ChildID,
    C.FirstName AS ChildFN,
    C.LastName AS ChildLN,
    M.PersonID AS MotherPersonID,
    M.FirstName AS MotherFN,
    M.LastName AS MotherLN 
FROM 
    PersonT C 
JOIN 
    PersonT M ON C.MotherID = M.PersonID 
ORDER BY 
    MotherPersonID
```

However, I want the result to be dependent on the record being viewed (so that only the children of the 'current record' person are shown). I would imagine that this would be achieved by referencing the textbox in the `PersonForm` that contains the `personID`, ie, the current record. but I can't figure out how to do this.

I attempted something like in access at the end of the self join query
`WHERE MotherID = Forms!PersonForm!PersonID` which was unsuccessful because you presumably can't refer to objects like this in T-SQL.

Is there something a bit like in MS Access, where you can refer to `Forms!FormName!ObjectName` etc in the query itself? It is possible I'm thinking about this in the wrong way.

Just in case it's relevant, here is the c# code

```
private void SearchButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter("THE SQL I PUT IN THE SECOND CODE SNIPPET", sqlCon);
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        sqlDA.Fill(dtbl);

        childOfCurrent.DataSource = dtbl;   //childOfCurrent is dataGridView object
    }
}
```

Comment: You normally create a parameterised query, and copy the form value into the parameter.

Comment: ok thanks @Nick.McDermaid I'll look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's the solution using a parameterised query, just in case anyone happens to have this question.**
context: each record in the form corresponds to a person, the objective is showing the children of any mother on the form in a datagridview using a self join on personID to motherID.

- solution takes the PersonID value( for example, 3) from the personID textbox to identify the current record. (this value changes depending on which record is open)
  This personID is set as the SQL parameter in line 8.
- the SQL query searches the database for records that have that personID value in their motherID column (this is the self join). (in other words, every record that lists MotherID = 3 as their mother is selected)
- solution returns the fields that match the criteria.
  This means that when a mother's record is open, the children can be displayed in the datagridview.

  ```
    private void showButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Table WHERE MotherID = @currentPerson", con); //currentperson is the parameter

                SCcmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentPerson", personIDTextBox.Text);  //this retrieves the PersonID value from the textbox

                DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
                cmd.Fill(dt); 
                DataGridViewName.DataSource = dt;
                cmd.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("complete");
                con.Close();

            }
        }
  ```